# script for capturing screen

Tags: bash, scripts, screenshot

I wanted to write a bash script that would take screenshots (using the `scrot` utility) of the entire screen every *x* seconds either for the next *y* hours from the initialization of the script or until I stop it myself. Can anyone help me with the syntax, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
START=`date +%H`
while [ $(( $(date +%H) - $y )) -lt $START ]; do
    scrot --delay $x
done
```

Read or replace `$x` and `$y` with values

Comment: Use `+%s` instead of `+%H` for more accuracy